# Create a script that looks at my memory card, and creates directory's on c:

Tags: windows, script

I am an avid photographer who is tired of creating new directories each time I want to copy the contents of my memory card to my c: drive.

Process is:

1. Insert SD card in laptop slot - (Always becomes d:\DCIM\100CANON )
2. Open folder
3. Open C:...\Pictures\Canon\2012
4. on D:\DCIM\100CANON (memory card), select entire day of photos > Copy
5. Back to C:...\Pictures\Canon\2012, and create new folder based on the "Date Modified" of the files selected  on D:
6. Paste files in newly created folder from #5

Repeat process for all dates on memory card....

Just wondering if someone know of a script language/program/ etc I could use to do this automatically?

Using  Windows - Vista :(

Comment: On Windows? I wouldn't have a clue. On Linux? It would probably be a lot easier. It might be possible to do it in a batch file, but I'm not a batch file expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I whole-heartedly concur with what Jeremy said. Photo management software makes such tedious workflows *so* much easier it's ridiculous! My personal favourite has to be [Downloader Pro](http://www.breezesys.com/Downloader/index.htm).

Mini feature list (details [here](http://www.breezesys.com/Downloader/features.htm)):

- Gives you a fast and simple way to transfer and store digital photos from your camera to PC
- Automatically rename and organize photos in a meaningful way as they are downloaded
- Save time locating images by assigning them recognizable and clear names and folders
  [image: 1]
- Specify download path using shooting data
- Create per-camera naming schemes
  [image: 2]
- Supports the downloading of JPEGs from all camera makes and raw files from most camera makes including Canon, Nikon, Olympus, Pentax, Fuji, Sony , Kodak, Leica, Sigma and Hasselblad
- Avoid duplicating images on your PC; Downloader Pro identifies duplicate images and only downloads them once. Particularly useful when downloading from mass storage devices
- Simplify workflow by automating the creation of sets of related directories for each download directory e.g. Vacation2009\originals, Vacation2009\working, JobXYZ\final
- Time saving automatic rotation of JPEGs from cameras with orientation sensors
- Store caption and location information in image IPTC/XMP data as images are downloaded
- Automatically geo-tag images using GPS data from devices like the Sony GPS-CS1 tracker, Garmin eTrex Venture CX etc.
- Ease reorganization of existing photos held on PC
- Photoshop users can automatically adjust dpi of JPEGs to their preferred value during download
- Photoshop users can automatically tag JPEGs with colour profile according to camera model

I started off rolling my own batch-based solution (as you are contemplating), but as it slowly grew more complex and I switched languages more than once, I grew tired of reinventing the wheel. After a bit of looking around I found this and have been using it ever since. So what I'm saying is, scripting a basic solution is most definitely possible, but if you do this on a regular basis and want to save time, you know what to do. :)

Comment: Woah!  I never knew about that program before.   Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this in any scripting language, with a little effort.

As for a program, there are lots of photo management programs, eg Lightroom. These give you much better options for managing your photos than simply folders of the date they were taken. Consider this: in a few months time, when you want to find photos again, and you want to get the photo you took of the Golden Gate Bridge on your visit to San Fransisco, are you going to remember that you took it on 20120514, or would it be easier to look for /Trips/SanFransisco ? Or search for a tag you have added, "bridge" or "goldengate"? If you do know the date taken, because the files still have the Date Created, you can still search or sort by Date Created, so that you can also find them that way. But if you organise the folders by date, that is the *only* option you have to find your pic...

Comment: Hi Jeremy, I have followed this method in the past for a couple of years, but it quickly became cumbersome and a complete mess. I do have Lightroom, and really need to look at what import features are built in.

Comment: Just remember: you can always search for files by date no matter what system you use. Taking the extra time at import to add additional information might seem like a cumbersome addition, but you'll appreciate the effort later.